# Include an eps from a certain folder

Tags: graphics, windows

How do I include a log from a certain folder in windows to a latex `\includegraphics`?

This doesn't work:

```
\includegraphics[scale=.3]{"C:\Users\Johannes\SBW\Logos\sbw+neue-medien_cmyk.eps"}
```

Comment: try the separator of linux : /. I mean replace \ with /

Comment: Try with `\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Johannes/SBW/Logos/}}` (double pair of braces!) in the preamble, and `\includegraphics{sbw+neue-medien_cmyk.eps}`.

Comment: If the above doesn't work try to give \graphicspath{{C:/Users/Johannes/SBW/Logos}{Any/Other/Path}{./subpathofLatexDocument}} on your preamble

Comment: this also doesn't work: \includegraphics[scale=.4]{C:/Users/Johannes/SBW/Logos/sbw+neue-medien_cmyk.eps}

Comment: My images are in possibly in multiple folders

Comment: Just in case, did you compile with latex or pdflatex?